# RTSP Proxy implementation and testing

Tags: streaming, rtsp, wowza, rtcp

I'm trying to implement an RTSP proxy server in order to analyse RTCP packets and dynamically switch to higher or lower bitrate streams (served by Wowza).
Can someone recommend an existing opensource proxy (Java) and a client that allows me to set the proxy? I've tried to use VLC for testing but apparently VLC does not allow me to set the RTSP proxy. What alternatives exist, do I need to create my own client?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .Net my implementation is full featured and contains not only a RtspClient but also a RtspServer so you can pass the changes in the source back down to the clients seamlessly.

https://net7mma.codeplex.com/